# C++ using 'delete' to free heap allocated data inside vector?

Tags: vector, heap-memory, free

is it ok to do something like this to free data inside a vector?

```
std::vector<std::string*> vec;

~SomeClassDestructor()
{
    delete [] vec.data();
    vec.clear();
}
```

Comment: I assume `vec.data()` returns an array your class allocated with `new`, correct?  But no, your whole approach is probably a Bad Idea.  If you're going to use "new", then you should do it in your class constructor ... and only call "delete[]" in the class destructor.  And don't forget the [Rule of 0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  But it's probably better if you can avoid "new" and "delete[]" in the first place :)

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, all of the data in the vector was allocated with 'new'

Comment: You do not control the data inside a `std::vector`. This will result in a double-free. (Furthermore, the memory in a `std::vector` wasn't allocated with `new[]` anyway. It was allocated by `allocate()`.)